# Symfony2 storing data in session versus database calls every page load

Tags: php, database, symfony, session

I have a site built on Symfony 2 that is basically made up of various applications. Once an application is selected, I store that application's ID in a session variable. Then for every page load for that application, the database is queried for the details of that application.

Wouldn't it be more efficient to just store the application details in the session variable instead of just the application ID?

What are the down sides of storing the application details in that way, are there any security risks I need to worry about?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: how much data it is?

Comment: maybe youre on the search of effective caching and front-end accelerator called "varnish" . Using this there is no request to symfony at all if theres a cached version of the request

Comment: like @DRC said how much data is it and what type of data is it ? it's a form maybe you could partially save it so that the user could come back to the application in the future and finish it

Comment: better store only the reference (id) of the object in the session to keep it lightweight. Then you can easy configure a doctrine cache layer to keep the query result in memory for a while. Hope this help.

Comment: It's maybe 10 fields at the most, numbers and strings (< 255 chars). Basic info like, app id, app name, app description, etc.

Comment: To be more specific, it would an object that would be stored in the session, which contains the information mentioned above.

Comment: I'd recommend caching serialized objects in `Redis`, keeping it in front `mysql` db. Basically you need to solve this architecturally.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to store the app number at session at all. You deprive yourself from usage of shared `HTTP` caches with that approach http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#public-vs-private-responses as all your requests become `private` cause a response depends on SESSION value.

If you will move the app number to the url or header or etc you will get a lot of space for optimizations.

Usage of the DB to a get app info is a quite good practice as you are able to enable doctrine's result cache for this queries to make them not impact of the app performance at all. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache

Usage of the session to store app_id is bad practice but usage of the session to store the all app info is even worse as the number of session_ids is significant and you will store a lot of redundant information.